# Запись в Excel полученных данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, excel

Есть такая запись:

```
Ващенко Ирина Вениаминовна
Бидермейерская традиция в новелле Пауля Хейзе "Беатрис"
Гуманитарные научные исследования
//
Туранов Х.Т., Гордиенко А.А.
АНАЛИЗ РЕЗУЛЬТАТОВ ИССЛЕДОВАНИЙ ДВИЖЕНИЯ ВАГОНА ПРИ НЕПОСРЕДСТВЕННОМ ЕГО ТОРМОЖЕНИИ НА УЧАСТКАХ ТОРМОЗНЫХ ПОЗИЦИЙ СОРТИРОВОЧНОЙ ГОРКИ ПРИ ВСТРЕЧНОМ ВЕТРЕ
Транспорт: наука, техника, управление
//
Гадельшин Марат Шавкатович, Кибардин Алексей Владимирович, Долгирев Юрий Евгеньевич, Закиров Айдар Ахматнурович, Скворцов Даниил Вячеславович
ИССЛЕДОВАНИЕ РАБОТЫ ПЛОСКОЙ ТЕПЛОВОЙ ТРУБЫ ПРИ СЛОЖНЫХ ТЕПЛОВЫХ НАГРУЗКАХ
Проблемы современной науки и образования
//
```

Мне нужно всех авторов поместить в одну колонку, но в разных ячейках. Если авторов несколько, то строки, с наименованием статей и издательства, размножаются.

Попыталась сделать это через xlwt

```
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('Выгрузка')
ws.write(0, 0, authors)
ws.write(0, 1, title_book)
ws.write(0, 2, journal_title)
wb.save('table1.xls')
```

Но у меня получаются все авторы в одной ячейке и почему-то только последняя запись. Подскажите, как корректно записать в Excel данные? Заранее благодарна за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в данном случае я бы воспользовался модулем Pandas:

```
import re
import pandas as pd    # pip install pandas

text = """Ващенко Ирина Вениаминовна
Бидермейерская традиция в новелле Пауля Хейзе "Беатрис"
Гуманитарные научные исследования
//
Туранов Х.Т., Гордиенко А.А.
АНАЛИЗ РЕЗУЛЬТАТОВ ИССЛЕДОВАНИЙ ДВИЖЕНИЯ ВАГОНА ПРИ НЕПОСРЕДСТВЕННОМ ЕГО ТОРМОЖЕНИИ НА УЧАСТКАХ ТОРМОЗНЫХ ПОЗИЦИЙ СОРТИРОВОЧНОЙ ГОРКИ ПРИ ВСТРЕЧНОМ ВЕТРЕ
Транспорт: наука, техника, управление
//
Гадельшин Марат Шавкатович, Кибардин Алексей Владимирович, Долгирев Юрий Евгеньевич, Закиров Айдар Ахматнурович, Скворцов Даниил Вячеславович
ИССЛЕДОВАНИЕ РАБОТЫ ПЛОСКОЙ ТЕПЛОВОЙ ТРУБЫ ПРИ СЛОЖНЫХ ТЕПЛОВЫХ НАГРУЗКАХ
Проблемы современной науки и образования
//"""

def parse_text_to_df(text,
                     pat=r'([^\r\n]*)[\r\n]+([^\r\n]*)[\r\n]+([^\r\n]*)[\r\n]+\/\/',
                     columns = ['author','book_title','journal_title']):
    data = []

    for x in re.findall(pat, text):
        authors = x[0].split(', ')
        book_title = x[1]
        journal_title = x[2]
        for a in authors:
            data.append([a, book_title, journal_title])

    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)


df = parse_text_to_df(text)
df.to_excel(r'd:/temp/result.xlsx', index=False)
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! Все сработало!!!

Comment: @Ireen1985, всегда рад помочь (-:

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, еще такой момент. Пытаюсь добавить еще колонку. А мне выдает: tuple index out of range. Я не смогу добавить что-то в этот код?

Comment: @Ireen1985, а что должно быть в новом столбце?

Comment: я уже нашла решение. Спасибо Вам ещё раз!!!